# Code First Reverse Engineering can't change file name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, t4, dbcontext

In Entity Framework Power Tools Beta 3 I've used Customize Reverse Engineering Templates to change t4 files in order to rename my Entities classes, but I can't change the file names of those classes using the t4 file templates provided.

In the database I'm using all tables starts with "Tb" and I want to remove that prefix from my entities names. 
Does anyone know how to do it using Code First Reverse engeneering? Do I need to change all files names manually?

Comment: Potentially you could hack the T4 templates to get the behavior you want.

Comment: The T4 templates only allow to change entity class file. I can't change the file name.

Comment: So modify the T4 templates so that they *do* allow you to change the file name.

Comment: Not a very helpful comment. It's not trivial to do this with the supplied T4 templates.

Comment: Modal code in the database for each change you have to change the file or delete the folder and again you need to do is reverse engineering.